# Law of parallel programming

Tags: parallel-processing

There is a law of parallel programming but I can't find a link to it. Shortly it tells the following: if 1/3 of time your program is executed sequentially (in one thread), you can increase your application performance only 3 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Answer (score 5):

Amdahl's law refers to the old single-core CPUs. You may want to read carefully what happens on current multi-core CPUs. See

[Amdahl's Law in the Multicore Era](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/multifacet/papers/ieeecomputer08_amdahl_multicore.pdf)

and the related [page](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/multifacet/amdahl/) where you will find additional resources.

Comment: Thanks! Really interesting paper. The's a video link on the related page which is also good (Google TechTalk).